# jQuery: Unbind jQuery 2.0 on method

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery 1.9 `live()` was deprecated, so the new method became:

```
$(document).on("mouseover","*",blahblahfunc);
```

I'm unable to unbind "blahblahfunc".
via

```
$("*").unbind("mouseover mouseout click");
```

Notice that I'm binding a function to every element in the dom, any ideas?

Comment: ha, I feel dumb, I should have realized that! Thanks for clearing up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.off()`

see the Api Documentation

http://api.jquery.com/off/

> The off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()

```
$(document).on("mouseover","*",blahblahfunc);
$(document).off("mouseover","*",blahblahfunc);
```

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of `$("selector").on(...)` is `$("selector").off(...)`. See http://api.jquery.com/off/ Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You bound the event to the document, therefore you have to unbind it from the document.

```
$(document).off("mouseover","*",blahblahfunc);
```